# Where to offer money for cracking check

Tags: rsa, password-cracking, drm

I made a software and I would like to distribute it as a demo that can be registered. I would like to know if there is a site where I can offer some  reward for some one try to crack my software and explain how it was done.
Thanks

Comment: How about security.stackexchange.com ? If you detail your protection scheme, I for one could try for free :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't spend a lot of money on this effort, because any software you distribute can be  cracked.  Unless you're distributing expensive hardware keys, or creating a server-side component, any end-user copy protection scheme can be broken.

Instead, you can make it complex enough to thwart most people (it sounds like you've already done this.) Also, you could appeal to your users to be trustworthy and not to share copies.  Relying on a service to perform an important feature works for products like Microsoft's Office365.